# Insert text inside an android switch material

Tags: android, switch-statement, material-components-android

Hi guys I'm trying to make the text "text_on / text_off" appear inside the thumb of the switch material. I created my own thumb, used to use the  element and it worked, now I'm using SwitchMaterial and the text has disappeared. Is there a way to put "on / off" text inside the switch material?

I refer to this text:

```
            android:textOff="@string/no"
            android:textOn="@string/yes"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using

> app:showText="true"

instead of

> android:showText="true"